# IP Camera Integration error with AWS Kinesis Video Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, ip-camera

I have a requirement to stream the IP camera into amazon Kinesis, What I have done for the Camera Interface I have used the AWS EC2 Instance for capturing the video so I have setup all the processes and the Installation was successful. Currently, I'm getting error when I start the process.

`gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://xxx:xxpassword@123:12:123:4:554/1" short-header=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264, format=avc,alignment=au ! h264parse ! kvssink stream-name="ABCD" storage-size=512 access-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" secret-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" aws-region="us-east-2"`

The Error what I'm getting is:

[image: AWS EC2 Instance I'm getting this error any idea how to resolve this]